# import not seeing modules in a package, inconsistent between two imports

Tags: python, import

I have a peculiar problem with importing modules in some code I am working on.  The directory layout is:

```
main.py
cm1sinit/
   __init__.py
   MainInterface.py
   soundings/
      __init__.py
      WK82.py
   hodographs/
      __init__.py
      curved90.py
```

__init__.py in all cases is a 0-length empty file.

In MainInterface.py I have the following imports:

```
import soundings
import hodographs
```

and calling dir() or inspect.getmembers() on each of these produces:

```
dir(soundings)
['WK82', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

dir(hodographs)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Why is the soundings import picking up its module WK82 while the hodographs import is not picking up curved90?  I am trying to dynamically produce pyQt widgets that are populated just by adding files to the module directories.  This works for the sounding module but not for hodographs.

I can remedy this by using:

```
import hodographs.curved90
dir(hodographs)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'curved90']
```

but this defeats the purpose of not having to explicitly name the imports in my dynamic content generation.

How can I fix this so that 'import hodographs' is properly importing all files in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a package, only the package (that is, what's defined in `__init__.py`) is initialized and imported -- the sub-packages and modules contained in the package aren't automatically imported.

For that to happen, you need to edit your `__init__.py` files so that they look like this:

```
# cms1init/soundings/__init__.py
from cms1init.soundings import WK82
```

That way, the `WK82` module is imported and made available as an attribute of `cms1init.soundings`. Just repeat the maneuver for the `cms1init.hodographs` package.

Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense, but why am I getting away with not doing that in soundings but still having it work.  I have a similar solution to what you posted (import curved90 in hodographs/__init__.py).  Any clues as to why 'import soundings' (and empty __init__.py) is working without any explicit references to the modules?  (or is it just a bug I'm finding helpful).

Comment: Probably because your ``import soundings`` is in a module at the same level as ``soundings`` in the file system hierarchy -- that is, at the root of the ``cms1init`` directory.

Comment: That is true. The `import soundings` and `import hodograps` are both in the same file in the `cm1sinit` directory. Same file, same filesystem hierarchy, same module layouts, same imports; different behavior. I have a suitable (though non-optimal) fix that is compatible with your answer so I'll accept it later. I'm still curious as to why the behavior is different though.